# Reusuing UI for each quest in Quizz app?

Tags: android

I've a scenario where users take a quiz that has 40+ question. Creating 40+ activities is tedious task & i want to know is there anything exists to reuse?

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
   >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Who founded Apple?"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text="Fill answers here"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
        android:clickable="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my MainActivity.class, im normally doing like

```
Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               // ....Go to next activity through Intent...
            }
        });
```

Look inside onClick, I need to have each activity for each question that is not good.

Any other solution?

Comment: Are you fetching those question text from database ?

Comment: You're right that 40 activities would be stupid.  But if you're at the stage where how to do this is even a question, you need to think through how to do things, not be spoon fed an answer.  Think about this-  what data is needed for each question?  How can you change the UI to display that data?  When do I need to do that?  Once you figure out those things there should be an obvious way forward.

Comment: @Ajeet : Yes, from database.

Comment: @GabeSechan : "How can you change the UI to display that data" Since i don't know and couldn't find i'm asking here. Why should i ask if i get any links or tuts?

Comment: Have you successfully retrieved data from database ?

Comment: @Ajeet : Yes, but that's not a question i've asked.

Comment: You really couldn't google and find an answer for "android change string textview"?

Comment: See You're just asking me a questions like a Teacher instead of providing some useful answers. I know how to change the TextView. My problem was replacing and re-using the same UI. If you can't provide any good solution, you can ignore this thread. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a teacher is not useful?

Comment: I don't said Teacher is not useful. I said you are just asking questions to me instead of teaching anything lol. I would've got any useful idea now if you would ve stopped questioning and provided some useful links/codes/tuts in these time.

Comment: The question seems a little bit useless. Simply go back and forth and repopulate the data in your TextViews (I use a ListView instead, but the concept is the same).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a data structure for your quizes if you haven't. Once you have a datastructure you can think about what kind of adapter you want to use: that is, the mechanism that will link your set of quizes to the UI. For instance, when needing to display a list of something, listview is used with an ArrayAdapter (or BaseAdapter for more custom styled listview).

In the support libraries there is something called a viewpager, which is a set of pages you can swipe horizontally between. You might consider using this.

Or you can create your own view class that has all the views you need to display the quiz, add a method like `switchQuiz(Quiz q)` which changes the ui with the new quiz information, and use this view in a single activity. Specifically you can take your `activity_main.xml` layout file, and instead of using it as the layout of an activity, make a custom view (`public class QuizView extends RelativeLayout { }`) that has a a way to update the ui for the switch quiz functionality. Read here for more information of how to do this: http://trickyandroid.com/protip-inflating-layout-for-your-custom-view/

Answer (score 0):

Create two buttons, prev and next..

prev take you to prev question and next take you next question

Create a class question containing following variable

```
int number_of_option;
    String[] options;
    String question;
    String answer;
```

Create a class quiz containing `ArrayList<question> list;`
add required method to add question, get question , update answer..etc..etc

Create variable current_position_in_UI in quiz class to display that question in activity.

On next/prev button click call a method of quiz to get question fields. something like list.get(position) and  update your views with those values on that call. Also update your current_position_in_UI. Hope it helps :)